# Stuck trying to get datepicker to play nice with a set date for second date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

Question is I have two date pickers what called leave_start the other leave_end. I have some custom things going on to block out weekends and set a minDate as today and also block out custom holidays. I however cant seem to figure out why I cant grab the val date from the first date picker(leave_start) and set it as a minDate in my second datepicker(leave_end). Everything else works great just cant seem to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Side note this is a ruby on rails app 
Using jquery datepicker.

Here is my Application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    var penn = ["2015-01-01", "2015-04-03", "2015-05-25", "2015-07-03", "2015-09-07", "2015-11-26", "2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"];
    var start = $("#leave_start").val();

    $('#leave_start').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var weekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
            if (weekend[0]) {
                var holidays = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [penn.indexOf(holidays) == -1];
            } else {
                return weekend;
            } 
        }
     });
     $('#leave_end').datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
         minDate: start,
         beforeShowDay: function(date) {
             var weekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

             if (weekend[0]) {
                 var holidays = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                 return [penn.indexOf(holidays) == -1];

             } else {
                 return weekend;
             }
          }
      });
}):
```

Comment: what are you using for initial value for start date? Are you expecting min date to update dynamically when start selected? Right now you only set minDate based on page load value

Comment: yes I want to set minDate dynamically. for example once a user picks a date for leave_start  say sometime in August. Instead of my second datepicker starting at mindate 0 which is today July. I would like it to dynamically load the my leave end datepicker to show dates after the leave start date. @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a change event handler on the first `datepicker` to update `minDate` of the second.

Simple Example:

```
$('#date1').datepicker();
$('#date2').datepicker();

$('#date1').change(function() {
    $( "#date2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", $('#date1').val() );
});
```

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jon3xt3e/1/

**EDIT**

Example using your settings and javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var penn = ["2015-01-01", "2015-04-03", "2015-05-25", "2015-07-03", "2015-09-07", "2015-11-26", "2015-12-25", "2016-01-01"];
    var start = $("#leave_start").val();

    $('#leave_start').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var weekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
            if (weekend[0]) {
                var holidays = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                return [penn.indexOf(holidays) == -1];
            } else {
                return weekend;
            } 
        }
     });
     $('#leave_end').datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
         minDate: start,
         beforeShowDay: function(date) {
             var weekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);

             if (weekend[0]) {
                 var holidays = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                 return [penn.indexOf(holidays) == -1];

             } else {
                 return weekend;
             }
          }
      });

     $('#leave_start').change(function() {
        $( "#leave_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", $('#leave_start').val() );
     });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jon3xt3e/2/

Comment: ahhh thank you @DDan !!! That worked great sorry I didn't respond back until now!

Comment: No probs! I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onSelect` method of the first to change the option of the second. your current attempt will only get the value of the input on page load so it requires binding to events to make the changes as well as using the API to change options

```
function beforeShow(date) {
  var weekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
  if (weekend[0]) {
    var holidays = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [penn.indexOf(holidays) == -1];
  } else {
    return weekend;
  }
}
$(function() {

  var start = $("#leave_start").val();

  $('#leave_start').datepicker({        
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(date, ui) {
      $leave.datepicker('option', {'minDate': date});
    },
    beforeShowDay: beforeShow
  });

  var $leave = $('#leave_end').datepicker({
    minDate: start,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(d, ui) {
      //do something when leave selected
    },
    beforeShowDay: beforeShow
  });

});
```

Also note that you have `beforeShowDay` property twice in your plugin definition objects

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PBdd8yYPL193MhD8hhy0?p=preview)</kbd>